# How to ensure that a cryptographic implementation is reasonably sound/robust?

Tags: implementation, randomness, entropy, cryptographic-hardware, timing-attack

I know from the bottom of my heart how bad the idea of custom-crypto is. I absolutely concur with the recommendation that it should only be done by professionals who specialize in implementing crypto safely.

However, exactly because it's a Bad Idea ™ it's really hard to find good information on this topic. Say one of the aforementioned professionals is looking at a crypto implementation and they want to judge how safe it is. Some things that come to mind:

- Constant-time implementation (to protect against timing/side-channel attacks)
- Randomness

  - Source of randomness (true vs. pseudo RNGs)
  - Bits of entropy
- Zeroing intermediate buffers
- Appropriate test coverage with test vectors (e.g., NIST, Wycheproof)

What are other areas like this that need to be probed? Is there any documentation/checklist/book that can shed further light on the topic -- something like [1](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Ejkatz/security/downloads/kohno.pdf) but more comprehensive?

Comment: It depends on the type of cryptography what kind of attacks can be mounted. Without it all cryptographic attacks ever would fit the bill, because a non-cryptographer (and, quite often, even cryptographers) are bound to repeat past mistakes.

Comment: Another one that comes to mind: who wrote it? While not a determining factor, if the software is written by someone known to write good cryptographic code, that's certainly a plus. If it's someone new (like myself), it's reason to be more cautious.

Answer (score 2):

One widely accepted standard for information protection is the ISO [Common Criteria framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Criteria). This [set of slides](https://www.commoncriteriaportal.org/iccc/ICCC_arc/presentations/T2_D2_11_30am_Vora_Crypto_and_CC.pdf) gives some sense of what a Common Criteria evaluation will ask in its analysis.

The US [FIPS-140-3](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.140-3.pdf) standard also carries a lot of weight, it specifies certain NIST special publications that give criteria beyond ISO.